# In Django Rest Framework, how can I do a bulk create with foreign key

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-views, bulk

I have three tables:

```
    BODYPART_CHOICES = (
        ('Abs', 'Abs'), ('Ankle', 'Ankle'),
        ('Back', 'Back'), ('Biceps', 'Biceps'),
        ('Cervical', 'Cervical'), ('Chest', 'Chest'), ('Combo', 'Combo'),
        ('Forearms', 'Forearms'), ('Full Body', 'Full Body'),
        ('Hip', 'Hip'),
        ('Knee', 'Knee'),
        ('Legs', 'Legs'), ('Lower Back', 'Lower Back'), ('Lumbar', 'Lumbar'),
        ('Neck', 'Neck'),
        ('Shoulders', 'Shoulders'),
        ('Thoracic', 'Thoracic'), ('Triceps', 'Triceps'),
        ('Wrist', 'Wrist'),
    )

    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('Cardio', 'Cardio'),
        ('Stability', 'Stability'),
        ('Flexibility', 'Flexibility'),
        ('Hotel', 'Hotel'),
        ('Pilates', 'Pilates'), ('Power', 'Power'),
        ('Strength', 'Strength'),
        ('Yoga', 'Yoga'),
        ('Goals & More', 'Goals & More'),
        ('Activities', 'Activities'),
        ('Rehabilitation', 'Rehabilitation'),
        ('Myofascial', 'Myofascial')
    )

    EQUIPMENT_CHOICES = (
        ('Airex', 'Airex'),
        ('BOSU', 'BOSU'), ('Barbell', 'Barbell'), ('Battle Rope', 'BattleRope'), ('Bodyweight', 'Bodyweight'),('Bands', 'Bands'),
        ('Cables', 'Cables'), ('Cones', 'Cones'),
        ('Dumbbells', 'Dumbbells'), ('Dyna Disk', 'Dyna Disk'),
        ('Foam Roller', 'Foam Roller'),
        ('Kettlebells', 'Kettlebells'),
        ('Leg Weights', 'Leg Weights'),
        ('Machine', 'Machine'), ('Medicine Ball', 'Medicine Ball'),
        ('Plate', 'Plate'), ('Power Wheel', 'Power Wheel'),
        ('Ring', 'Ring'),
        ('Sandbag', 'Sandbag'), ('Stick', 'Stick'), ('Strap', 'Strap'), ('Suspension', 'Suspension'), ('Swiss Ball', 'Swiss Ball'),
        ('Theraball', 'Theraball'), ('Towel', 'Towel'), ('Tubbing', 'Tubbing'),
        ('Wobble Board', 'Wobble Board'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    photograph = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=exercise_image_file_path)
    body_part = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=BODYPART_CHOICES)
    equipment = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=EQUIPMENT_CHOICES)
    equipment_two = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=EQUIPMENT_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    workout_tip = models.TextField(max_length=3000, blank=True)
    cmf_url = models.URLField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    vimeo_exercise_id = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    # exercise_id =  models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Workout(models.Model):
    GOALS_CHOICES = (
        ('None', 'None'),
        ('Abs', 'Abs'), ('Arms', 'Arms'),
        ('Cardio', 'Cardio'), ('Core', 'Core'),
        ('Endurance', 'Endurance'),
        ('Flexibility', 'Flexibility'), ('Full Body', 'Full Body'),
        ('Legs', 'Legs'), ('Lower Body', 'Lower Body'),
        ('Power', 'Power'),
        ('Shoulders', 'Shoulders'), ('Sport Conditioning', 'Sport Conditioning'), ('Stability', 'Stability'), ('Strength', 'Strength'),
        ('Toning', 'Toning'),
        ('Upper Body', 'Upper Body'),
        ('Weight Loss', 'Weight Loss')
    )

    exercises = models.ManyToManyField(Exercise, through='Targets')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=SET_NULL,null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=3000, blank=True)
    goals = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=GOALS_CHOICES, default='None')
    workout_time = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='Created')
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=timezone.now())
    assigned = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    completed = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True,
                                    validators=[MaxValueValidator(5),
                                    MinValueValidator(0)])
    overall_note = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Targets(models.Model):
    EXERCISE_SET_CHOICES = (
        ('Set', 'Set'),
        ('Superset', 'Superset'),
        ('Triple Set', 'Triple Set'),
        ('Quad Set', 'Quad Set'),
        ('Dropset', 'Dropset'),
        ('Circuit', 'Circuit'),
        ('Pyramid', 'Pyramid'),
        ('Interval', 'Interval'),
        ('Tabata', 'Tabata'),
    )
    WEIGHT_CHOICES = (
        ('Bodyweight', 'Bodyweight'),
        ('Pounds', 'Pounds'),
    )
    REPS_CHOICES = (
        ('Reps', 'Reps'), ('Secs','Secs')
    )

    workout = models.ForeignKey(Workout, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, related_name='targets')
    exercises = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    sets = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    exercise_set = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=EXERCISE_SET_CHOICES, default='Set')
    reps = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    reps_choice = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='Reps', choices=REPS_CHOICES)
    rest = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    exercise_notes = models.TextField(max_length=3000,blank=True )
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    weight_measurements = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=WEIGHT_CHOICES, default='Bodyweight')
    client_notes = models.TextField(max_length=3000, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.workout.name, self.exercises.name)
```

As you can see, the Target model is my through table for my Workout model. When I create my targets, I am using bulk create. I am unable to save my workout or my exercise to the target. Each target will have the same workout, but each target will have a different exercise.

When creating my workout, I did this to save the profile:

```
def post(self, request):
        profile=request.data.pop('profile')
        serializer = WorkoutSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            profile_id=int(profile['id'])
            profile = Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id)
            serializer.save(profile=profile)
            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

but this wont work for the Targets since I will have to create to many for loops and it will slow everything down.
Why is Django not saving the data with the foreign key and this extra step must be done? How can I save my workout and exercise in their target?